# How to update true/false field in access using c#?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, ms-access-2013

My code is:

```
private void setGrant()
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT grant FROM UsrDet WHERE usrname = '" + this.usrname.Text + "' AND usrpasswd = '" + this.passwd.Text +"';";
            using (OleDbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while(dr.Read())
                {
                    bool permsn = Convert.ToBoolean(dr["grant"]);
                    if (permsn == false)
                    {
                        permsn = true;
                        OleDbCommand c1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE UsrDet SET grant = '" + permsn.ToString() + "' WHERE usrname = '" + this.usrname.Text + "';", con);
                        c1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Access Denied.");
                    }
                 }
            }
        }
```

On executing it shows an exception:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.

My problem is I want to update the value of grant(true/false field) in my access database based on the previous value in it.

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement looks fine to me (unless `grant` is a reserved word in Access), `bool.ToString` would return a [TrueString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.truestring(v=vs.110).aspx) / [FalseString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.falsestring(v=vs.110).aspx) which Access expects. Could you post more information about the error? However, you should almost certainly be using SQL parameters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to drop the quotes, since those will make it a text variable. Also, since `grant` is a reserved keyword, use brackets around it:

```
OleDbCommand c1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE UsrDet SET [grant] = " + permsn + " WHERE usrname = '" + this.usrname.Text + "';", con);
```

I would advise you to use parameters though.

```
OleDbCommand c1 = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE UsrDet SET [grant] = ? WHERE usrname = ?;", con);
c1.Parameters.Add("?", permsn);
c1.Parameters.Add("?", this.usrname.Text);
```

Comment: even though the unhandled exception persists

Comment: Even with the brackets around `grant`?